# React how to use array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm making a Project for Cat lover
but When I use a API, I got a Problem.
I got below this  data
but I want a get createdDate data like this 05-04
I Tried  like this  nowaDays[0].createdDate.substr(5, 5)` but I got only  05-04"

This is what I want

```
0: {id: 244, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 4}
1: {id: 245, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 5}
2: {id: 246, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 6}
3: {id: 247, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 6}
4: {id: 248, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 7}
5: {id: 249, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 8}
6: {id: 250, createdDate: "05-04", weight: 9}
```

[image: this is original API]

This picture what i got

Comment: FYI, nothing related to react in this question. Are you aware of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? It is used to transform data.

Comment: I don't see `testDays` declared anywhere. Can you add that bit of relative code? You also may want to use a Date-helper library (like momentjs) to help with date formatting. Lastly, your `.substr(5, 5)` is likely to blame regarding the result of `05-04"`

Comment: @MarkC. Thanks for reply Mark ! I Updated some code Let me check momentsJS !

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for reply crashmstr ! yes I know when I use map i got only seven  05-04 data

Comment: @marsoon You definitely don't show any code using `map` nor what function you pass into map. If you return an object that has `id`, `createDate`, and `weight`, you would have more than just "05-04" seven times.

Comment: `data.map(x => ({ ...x, createDate: transformDate(x.createDate)}))`?

Comment: @crashmstr omg it works!!!! Thank you so much my friend Have a good day !!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you could approach this:

1. If you only want to pass "05-04", that should be handled at the API level, not with React.
2. What I'd recommend is that you accept the full date, but then format it to the user using moment.js or another Date library. [Visit this site](https://momentjs.com/docs) for how to do that.

Comment: Thanks I will check your advice!